# How do I wait for javax.xml.validation.Validator to finish validating before moving on to the following statement?

Tags: java, xml, validation

Well, the title says it all.

I know that it is not a blocking call but I need to wait for it to  finish validating before moving on to the next statement.

How can I do that ?

### My ErrorHandler class

```
private class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler{
        public SAXParseException ex = null;
        public boolean errorOccured = false;

        @Override
        public void error(SAXParseException ex) {
            this.ex = ex;
            errorOccured = true;
        }

        @Override 
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException ex){
            this.ex = ex;
            errorOccured = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void warning(SAXParseException ex){

        }


}
```

Comment: Do you need to do something else while you wait? If not, surely there is nothing else you need to do but wait for the call to return or handle any exceptions thrown.

Comment: @JamesB exatcly what I want to do. I just want to see if errors were generated. if yes, terminate the application

Comment: @JamesB Since all the errors generated are sent to the `ErrorHandler`,  I need to wait for it to return and see if any errors were generated while validating. If yes, terminate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "I know that it is not a blocking call". What makes you think that?

`Validator.validate` is a blocking call.

If you want to validate the document then check for errors you can create your own `ErrorHandler`

```
final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
final List<SAXParseException> errors = new ArrayList<SAXParseException>();
validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

    public void warning(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        //ignore, log or whatever
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        errors.add(saxpe);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        //parsing cannot continue
        throw saxpe;
    }
});
final Source source = new StreamSource(new File("my.xml"));
validator.validate(source);
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    //there are errors.
}
```

Or you can throw the errors out to abort validation on the first error

```
final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

    public void warning(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        //ignore, log or whatever
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        throw saxpe;
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException saxpe) throws SAXException {
        //parsing cannot continue
        throw saxpe;
    }
});
final Source source = new StreamSource(new File("my.xml"));
validator.validate(source);
```